# The initial "display" property of an element is empty in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a simple menu using HTML and CSS. The menu will initially be displayed or not depending on the width of the canvas window. After that, the user will be able to display or hide the menu.

I am trying to use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
#showmenu, #hidemenu {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #8f8;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  #showmenu { display: none; }
  #hidemenu { display: inline-block; }
  #pagemenu { display: block; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #showmenu { display: inline-block; }
  #hidemenu { display: none; }
  #pagemenu { display: none; }
}
</style>
<script>
function toogleMenu(x) {
  alert(document.getElementById("showmenu").style.display);
  if (document.getElementById("showmenu").style.display!=="none") {
    document.getElementById("showmenu").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("hidemenu").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("pagemenu").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("showmenu").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("hidemenu").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("pagemenu").style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<body>
<p>
  <span onclick="toogleMenu(this)" id="showmenu"> ≡ </span>
  <span onclick="toogleMenu(this)" id="hidemenu"> × </span>
  SOME TITLE...
</p>
<p id="pagemenu">Menu<br>1111<br>2222<br>3333</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that during the first click by the user (= the first invocation of `toogleMenu` function) I cannot get the current CSS `display` property for either element with `showmenu` or `hidemenu` tag: The initial value obtained is empty and it looks like it is not set by `@media screen ...` CSS. So, I am unable to determine whether `≡` or `×` is displayed after the page is fully rendered.

Note that after a first click of the `toogleMenu` function, everything works as expected.

How can I obtain the current CSS `display` property of an element in JavaScript just after the page is displayed?

Comment: I strongly recommend (a) **not** twiddling `style.FOO` directly (b) toggling [the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) of a single parent element and using it with descendant combinators in your stylesheet and (c) using [accessibility patterns](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menubar/)